# Finding size of RAM on a remote computer

Tags: windows, powershell

I am attempting to find the size of the RAM on a remote computer on the domain. Here is the relevant part of the powershell script I have:

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName {Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem} | 
    where {$_.Free -gt 0} | 
    select pscomputername,Root,@{name="RAM (GB)";expression={"{0:N3}"
        -f (($_.TotalPhysicalMemory)/1gb)}}
```

The script executes without any errors, however, shows "0.00" as the output for the installed RAM. This is of course incorrect and I have tried running this on several remote computers.

Any tips would be appreciated as I am a beginner in PS.

Comment: We'll start with the fact that `Get-PSDrive -PSProvider FileSystem` gets you information about logical drives on a computer, such as hard drives, not about RAM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try

```
Invoke-Command -ComputerName $ComputerName {Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem} | select @{name="RAM (GB)";e={[math]::Round($_.totalphysicalmemory/1GB,0)}}
```

and as what i know filesystem provider refers to the Disk Drive.